# How to force an audio file (mp3) to download in javascript

Tags: javascript, download

I am creating a system such that when a user clicks on a download link of an audio it redirect the user to the download page with countdown of 15 seconds, after the countdown the file should download.
This is what i have done so far:
HTML part:

```
<div id="url" hidden>
    http://media.dawahnigeria.com/dnlectures/Shaykh%20M.%20Yahya%20As%20Salafy%20(Kaduna)/Ramadan%201439/Shaykh%20Yahya%20As-Salafy%20-%20Ramadan%201439%20Tafseer%20(Day%2002)%20-%20DN.amr
</div>  

<div id="loader">
    <span id="count">15</span> seconds left to download!<br>
    <progress value="0" max="15" id="progressBar"></progress>
</div><br>
```

JS part:

```
url = document.getElementById('url').innerHTML
function download(url) {
// $("#loader").show();
var timeleft = 15;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 15 - --timeleft;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML - 1;
    if(timeleft <= 0){
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        // console.log('yes');

        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = name;
        link.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
        delete link;
        //console.log(url);
    }

},1000);
}
$(window).load(function() {
  download(url);
});
```

This works for only **.amr** files, but does not work for **.mp3** files both in google chrome and firefox.
How can i make javascript to force the file to download?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To brute force all MP3 files on your server to download, you can add this code in your .htaccess file: `AddType application/octet-stream mp3 //You can add more file types here`